# Independent and identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Y=1/4(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4)$, where $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ and $X_4$ are i.i.d. r.v.s (independent and identically distributed random variables) with a Cauchy pdf $$f_X(x) = \frac{a}{\pi(x^2 + a^2)}$$
I need to solve the characteristic function of Y and pdf of Y.
I cannot apply Cauchy pdf to this problem, can you please give me directions to solve this problem?

Comment: I typeset your question with Latex. Please check that everything is as you intended.

Comment: I checked, thanks

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: NB: @rubik, it's not LaTeX, it's [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun yes and what is MathJax? An implementation of TeX/LaTeX for the browser, in Javascript.

Comment: @rubik Touché $\ddot\smile$

Comment: so any idea for the problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Find the characteristic function of $Y$ on base of: $$\phi_{Y}\left(t\right)=\mathbb{E}e^{itY}=\phi_{X}\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)^{4}$$ and have a good look at it. Most probably you will recognize this function and the PDF of $Y$ will be evident then.

Answer (score 0):

Since the characteristic function of $X_1$ is $e^{-a|t|}$, the characteristic function of $S=X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4$ is $e^{-4a|t|}$, so $S$ is still Cauchy distributed and the pdf of $S$ is given by:
$$ f_S(x) = \frac{4a}{\pi(x^2+(4a)^2))}.$$
This gives that the arithmetic mean of $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ has the same distribution of $X_1$.

Comment: i'm not familiar with this formula neither, can you please iterate one step further?